# mercurial ignore creation/modyfication date change on LInux

Tags: linux, mercurial

On Windows Mercurial ignores creation/modyfication time of file, as long as file itself didn't change. Linux can't apparently do that. In my job some people work on Windows and some on Linux machines and we have a lot of false-positive changes in mercurial.

Good example is when we regenerate Doctrine models from YML file. Most of them stay the same, changes are in one or two, but all get regenerated and I have to go through all of them and make sure, that it is safe to ignore their changes (revert) so they won't mess up mercurial commit.

Is there a way to make Linux see those files as Windows does?

By the way: I have checked and it is not related to EOL problem or UTF-8 BOM or other hidden characters. Only timestamps changes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Well, Mercurial on Linux does not commit a file if the mtime is the only change either :

```
~ $ mkdir test
~ $ cd test/
~/test $ hg init
~/test $ echo a > a
~/test $ ls -l 
total 4
-rw------- 1 user users 2 Jul 23 13:21 a
~/test $ hg add a
adding a
~/test $ hg commit -m "Adding a"
a
committed changeset 0:e7d3dddff169
~/test $ ls -l 
total 4
-rw------- 1 user users 2 Jul 23 13:21 a
~/test $ touch a
~/test $ ls -l 
total 4
-rw------- 1 user users 2 Jul 23 13:22 a
~/test $ hg status
~/test $ hg commit -m "Mtime changed on a" a
nothing changed
~/test $
```

It does not detect a change if the ctime is altered either :

```
~/test $ ls -l
total 4
-rw------- 1 user users 2 Jul 23 13:22 a
~/test $ rm a
rm: remove regular file ‘a’? y
~/test $ echo a > a
~/test $ ls -l
total 4
-rw------- 1 user users 2 Jul 23 14:27 a
~/test $ hg status
~/test $ hg commit -m "Ctime changed on a" a
nothing changed
~/test $
```

Comment: Yes, it's not only mtime. Files are regenerated from scratch. Afterwards they are completely the same, but recreated, so it's more like ctime issue. File is changed (from mercurial point of view) and not changed (from my and Windows point of view) in the same time.

Comment: I updated my response, ctime doesn't cut it either. Are you sure there is no change to the file? Did you try a before/after checksum comparison, with for example sha256sum?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far man. SHA sums are different, ctime, mtime are also different. Diff shows that every single line is different, but they are not. no newlines, no different characters. no clue ;)

Comment: Actually I can send you an example 2 files (before/after) so you can check them yourself.

Comment: Have you tried to look for differences using an hex editor, like dhex? I would happily have a look at them for you if you can upload them somewhere, as I don't think that there is any private message feature on stack overflow.

Comment: @wasil "Diff shows that every single line is different" means always only one - you got EOL-style problem. For any SCM it *is* content-change

Comment: I strongly agree with @LazyBadger .

Answer (score 1):

Consequence of the comments for Remi's answer

You have real troubles with EOL in cross-platform development

**Single possible** and **best** friend for team in this situation is [EOL Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EolExtension), which have to be enabled and used by all developers at the same time

- Ignore "this is considered a feature of last resort" warning - you haven't another good way, and because ["...if external forces dictate that these features are mandatory for using Mercurial, they're available..."](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FeaturesOfLastResort)
- Read description of extension **carefully**, pay special attention to topic, titled with IMPORTANT in text (otherwise you'll get **a lot of** *additional* headache in addition to old)
- Configure extension properly for your use-case

I heard about screaming, crying and tantrums, this extension related, from Windows users mostly, bad never had chances to use it in own real work (I'm Winboy and communicate with Winboys)